# How should I add a "widget" like element?

Tags: widgets, templates

I would like to add a custom slideshow like "template" which can be called in to other template files.

My first thought was to create exactly that; a separate `slideshow.php` template file which contained the relevant markup and `<script>`s. Ideally it would bring in it's own stylesheet too, however I'm not sure how that would work as `<link>` and `<style>` can't be anywhere except in `<head>` (at least [not yet](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp)).

Then I found out about wordpress widgets. Judging by the name and the nature of what I'm trying to do, I figured maybe this was the way to go. I don't know much about these widgets and what they do/how they work (the example template looked like a confusion of php which didn't really seem relevant for stuff I wanted to do), even after scanning through the relevant page in the wordpress codex.

Which approach seems more logical?
When should one use a template, and when should one use a widget?

---

<sub>I'm completely new to wordpress, so my terminology might not be correct.. For that matter, I might not be correct about a lot of things :P</sub>

Comment: Have you considered implementing it as a shortcode?  Then you can add it in almost any area that accepts content, like a post, page or widget.  Just call wp_enqueue_script() inside the shortcode handler to load your js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely up to you. Both approaches should do the same thing. I really do think that you having trouble with correct implementation of your first choice/approach.

What you are trying to do is correct using a separate  template for your slideshow and then calling it with `get_template_part()`. The problem it seems is your styling. Style tags are valid outside the `<head></head>` tags, this is wht you use for inline styles, however, it is not recommended to use inline styles as they are difficult to override with child themes and plugins and inline styles cannot be removed by simply dequeueing or deregistering it.

What is not allowed outside the `<head></head>` tags is link tags. That is invalid HTML should you do that.

Whether or not you decide to make use of a template part o a widget, you will have to load your styles, so with both approaches you are back to square one if you don't load your styles correctly. Here is how to load your styles correctly

- Create a new stylesheet and call it whatever you like, something like `slider-style.css`
- Add all your styling for your slider in this file.
- Enqueue your stylesheet with `wp_enqueue_style()` inside a function. If you need to load your stylesheet conditionally, use `wp_register_style()` to register the style and then enqueue your style conditionally
- Hook your function to `wp_enqueue_scripts`. This will add your styles to `wp_head`

Example:

Say your slider will only be used on the homepage, you can try the following

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_slider_styles', PHP_INT_MAX );
function enqueue_slider_styles() 
{
    wp_register_style( 'slider-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/slider-style.css' );
    if ( is_home() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'slider_styles' );
    }
}
```

This will now load your slider stylesheet only on the home page. I assumed a parent theme here, if you are using a child theme (which you should always use if you want to make changes to a theme you did not write yourself), then you should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` in place of `get_template_directory_uri()`

### REFERENCES:

- [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)
- [`wp_register_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style)
- [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

Comment: AFAIK [`<style>` *attributes*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/) are allowed on elements anywhere. [`<style>` *tags*](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/style) (elements) are only allowed in `<head>`. At least [according to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp)..

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I think we missed each other somewhere, I'm speaking specifically of inline styling where you use the normal style attribute to define your styles inline. What you are referring to where the style element is used with the link tag, then yes, it **has to be** inside the head tags. This is used when you are adding your stylesheets (**incorrectly**) to the head.